# Need to create a swap partition after installation but I already got 4 so GParted won't let me

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot, arch-linux

I'm dual-booting Windows 10 and Manjaro 17 and when I installed the latter I forgot to add a swap partition.

Noticed that and tried to create one from GParted but it is returning the following error when I click on 'New':

> It is not possible to create more than 4 primary partitions
>
> If you want more partitions you should first create an extended 
>   partition. Such a partition can contain other partitions. Because an 
>   extended partition is also a primary partition it might be necessary 
>   to remove a primary partition first.

**/dev/sda1** is the Windows system reserved partition.

**/dev/sda2** is the Windows boot partition.

**/dev/sda3** is the other NTFS partition I've been using to store stuff.

**/dev/sda4** is the Linux partition.

Already shrinked /dev/sda3 by about 8 GB which I want to use as swap.

Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: What Error do you get from gparted when trying this?

Comment: Quoted it below:

"It is not possible to create more than 4 primary partitions

If you want more partitions you should first create an extended partition. Such a partition can contain other partitions. Because an extended partition is also a primary partition it might be necessary to remove a primary partition first."

Can't add images for some reason.

Comment: You should do as directed: "You should first create an extended partition."  this requires you to delete a partition then recreate the partition you deleted and create the partition for the swap.  You should delete `dev/sda4` in order to accomplish this.

Comment: You don't need swap partition. Make a swap file.

Comment: It may be possible to convert one primary partition to a logical partition using `fixparts`. See [this page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) for details, and in particular the "Adjusting Your Partitions" section.

Answer (score 0):

This process is relatively easy.

You will have to delete a partition.

Create an Extended Partition

Create the additional partitions inside the extended partition.

OR  The hard way!

First research if your hardware supports GPT.

If it does then converting to GPT might make more sense.

Comment: If he has a second drive with enough spare unformatted space he can clone the partition onto that before deleting it. Then copy it back after creating the extension.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way may be to resize /dev/sda3 back to what it was and create a file on the disk to use as swap rather then a partition.    One way to do this is to issue a command

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap.file bs=1048576 count=X
```

Where X is the size of the swap partition in megabytes.

The next step is to format it -

```
mkswap /swap.file
```

Then add it to fstab as you would a partition, then type swapon -a to activate (or reboot)